# Why can we assume that a piecewise continuous function has a maximum?

Tags: analysis

In a proof I found in a book regarding the ODE $\dot{x}(t) = A(t)x(t)$ where $A$ is piecewise continuous on a compact interval I, it is assumed that the maximum $K = \max_I ||A(t)||$ exists. In my opinion this doesn't have to be the case. Take, for example, $I = [-1,1]$ and $A(t) = \frac{1}{t}$ for $t > 0$ and $A(t) = 0$ for $t \leq 0$. Is there a mistake in the book or am I just wrong somewhere?

Comment: Maybe the book is not saying that all A(t) piecewise continuous on a compact have a maximum, just that for this ODE we take an A(t) which has a maximum. This is a constraint on A(t) for it not too be too wild, and see what's comes out of it. Maybe the general case is treated later ?

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the discrepancy is that the book is 
probably using a different  definition of a piecewise continuous function which does not allow your example to hold.

Consider following definition of a piecewise
continuous function. Let $D_1, \ldots, D_m$ be
a finite partition of $D \subseteq  R^d$.
Let $\phi_k : D_k \rightarrow \{0,1\}$ be defined
such that $\phi_k({\bf x}) = 1$ if ${\bf x} \in D_k$ and
$\phi_k({\bf x}) = 0$ if ${\bf x} \notin D_k$.
Let $f_k : R^d \rightarrow R$ be a function 
with the property that $f_k$ is continuous on the closure of $D_k$.
The function 
$f = \sum_{k=1}^m f_k \phi_k $ is called piecewise 
continuous on D.

If D is bounded then
$D_1, \ldots, D_m$ are bounded. Therefore 
With this definition it follows
f is bounded on D when D is compact.